# Slow Qt resize on Gnome 3

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, qt

I am experiencing slow resize behaviour for Qt applications on Gome 3(.18) on Fedora 23. The problem is that the bounding window resizes faster than the contents and random flicker or whatever its called is temporarily visible in the corners. This does not happen with Gtk apps.  It also did not happen with any apps on KDE 5 with this PC.  Any ideas?

PS. I'm on Haswell integrated graphics.

Comment: This is unfortunately "normal" for X11 programs, although GTK3 (and possibly Qt) have their own workarounds such as framesync, incompatible with each other... Are you using GNOME in Wayland mode or with Xorg?

Comment: I'm using X11. I know its responsible for most problems but I am puzzled as to why KDE does not have this problem. And GTK also doesn't on either.

Comment: Like I said, they have custom workarounds, but these depend on cooperation between apps and WM, so gtk3's "framesync" protocol only works with gnome-shell for example. Presumably Qt has something that only works with KWin.

Comment: I guess that makes sense but I also guess "framesync" actually works with KWin because GTK apps run 100% on KDE?